# Minha aplicação não altera dados no banco

Tags: java, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, mvc

Estou desenvolvendo um *software* para uma videolocadora com MVC.

Está ocorrendo dois problemas: de não alterar os atributos das pessoas e exibir o seguinte erro:

> java.sql.SQLException: Column 'codigo' not found `.

Esse erro está dizendo que não existe a coluna código na tabela pessoa no meu banco de dados, mas tem a coluna código e está marcada como *primary key*.

Estou a 4 dias nisso pesquisando na internet e achei algumas dicas que não resolveram os dois problemas.

Classe VideoPessoa, da camada view:

```
public class VideoPessoa extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    PessoaController pessoaController;
    Pessoa pessoa;




    /**
     * Creates new form Pessoa
     */
    public VideoPessoa() {
        initComponents();

        new Conexao();
        pessoaController = new PessoaController();
        pessoa = new Pessoa();
        this.carregarPessoas();
         this.novaPessoa();
        this.habilitarCampos();

    }

public boolean alterarPessoa() {
        pessoa.setCodigo( Integer.parseInt(this.txtCodigo.getText()));
        pessoa.setNome(this.txtNome.getText());
        pessoa.setEndereco(this.txtEndereco.getText());
        pessoa.setBairro(this.txtBairro.getText());
        pessoa.setCPF(this.txtCPF.getText());
        pessoa.setSexo(this.txtSexo.getText());
        pessoa.setUf(this.txtUF.getText());
        pessoa.setCelular(this.txtCelular.getText());
        pessoa.setTelefone(this.txtTelefone.getText());
        pessoa.setCidade(this.txtCidade.getText());

        if (pessoaController.alterar(pessoa)) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Registro alterado com sucesso!");
             this.desabilitarCampos();
            this.carregarPessoas();
        } else {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Erro ao alterar os dados!", "ERRO", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }

        return true;

    }
```

Classe PessoaController:

```
public class PessoaController {

    private final PessoaDAO pessoaDAO;


    public PessoaController() {
        pessoaDAO = new PessoaDAO();


    }

 public boolean alterar( Pessoa pessoa ) {
        boolean retorno;



        retorno = pessoaDAO.alterar(pessoa);

        System.out.println("Pessoa: "+pessoa); 

        return retorno;
    }
```

Classe PessoaDAO, incluindo o método de alterar pessoas:

```
public class PessoaDAO {

    private Connection con;

    private final String SQLINSERT = " INSERT INTO pessoa(nome, endereco, bairro, sexo, telefone, celular, CPF, uf, cidade)"
            + " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ";

    private final String SQLPESSOAPELOCODIGO = "SELECT  nome, endereco, bairro, sexo, telefone, celular, CPF, uf, cidade"
            + " FROM pessoa"
            + " WHERE codigo=? ";

    private final String SQLSELECT = " SELECT  codigo, nome, endereco, bairro, sexo, telefone, celular, CPF,  uf, cidade FROM PESSOA";

    private final String SQLUPDATE = " UPDATE pessoa"
            + " SET nome = ?, "
            + " endereco = ?, "
            + " bairro   = ?, "
            + " sexo     = ?, "
            + " telefone = ?, "
            + " celular  = ?, "
            + " CPF      = ?, "
            + " uf       =?, "
            + " cidade   =? "
            + " WHERE codigo = ?";

    private final String SQLDELETE = "DELETE FROM pessoa"
            + " WHERE codigo = ?";

    private PreparedStatement psInsert, sqlPessoaPeloCodigo, sqlSelect, sqlUpdate, sqlDelete;

    public PessoaDAO() {

        con = Conexao.getConnection();
        try {
            psInsert = con.prepareStatement(SQLINSERT);
            sqlPessoaPeloCodigo = con.prepareStatement(SQLPESSOAPELOCODIGO);
            sqlSelect = con.prepareStatement(SQLSELECT);
            sqlUpdate = con.prepareStatement(SQLUPDATE);
            sqlDelete = con.prepareStatement(SQLDELETE);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PessoaDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    public Pessoa getPessoaPeloCodigo(int codigo) {

        Pessoa pessoa = null;
 try (

            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(SQLPESSOAPELOCODIGO)
        ) {
            ps.setInt(1, codigo);
            try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                if (!rs.next()) return null; // Não encontrou.
                // Instancia a nova pessoa.
                //Instancia o novo filme
                pessoa = new Pessoa();

                //Seta as informações no filme
                pessoa.setCodigo(rs.getInt("codigo"));
                pessoa.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
                pessoa.setEndereco(rs.getString("endereco"));
                pessoa.setBairro(rs.getString("bairro"));
                pessoa.setSexo(rs.getString("sexo"));
                pessoa.setTelefone(rs.getString("telefone"));
                pessoa.setCelular(rs.getString("celular"));
                pessoa.setCPF(rs.getString("CPF"));

                pessoa.setUf(rs.getString("uf"));
                pessoa.setCidade(rs.getString("cidade"));

            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PessoaDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return pessoa;
    }

public boolean alterar(Pessoa pessoa) {
        boolean retorno = false;
        try {
            sqlUpdate.setInt(1, pessoa.getCodigo());
            sqlUpdate.setString(2,pessoa.getNome());
            sqlUpdate.setString(3, pessoa.getEndereco());
            sqlUpdate.setString(4, pessoa.getBairro());
            sqlUpdate.setString(5, pessoa.getSexo());
            sqlUpdate.setString(6, pessoa.getTelefone());
            sqlUpdate.setString(7, pessoa.getCelular());
            sqlUpdate.setString(8, pessoa.getCPF());
            sqlUpdate.setString(9, pessoa.getUf());
            sqlUpdate.setString(10, pessoa.getCidade());


            sqlUpdate.executeUpdate();

            retorno = true;

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PessoaDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return retorno;
    }
```

Classe Conexao:

```
public class Conexao {

    private static Connection con;

    public Conexao() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sistemavideolocadora2", "root", "1234");

            System.out.println(" Conexão obtida!!! ");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

            System.out.println(" Conexão estabelecida com sucesso!!! ");
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        return con;


    }

    public static void closeConnection() {
        try {
            con.close();

            System.out.println(" Conexão fechada!!! ");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

            System.out.println(" Conexão finalizada com sucessso!!! ");
        }
    }


}
```

Erro:

```
Conexao obtida!
out 27, 2015 3:32:41 PM dao.PessoaDAO getPessoaPeloCodigo
GRAVE: null
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'codigo' not found.
Pessoa: Pessoa{nome=, endereco=, bairro=, sexo=, telefone=, celular=, CPF=, codigo=0, cidade=, uf=, pessoa=null}
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1167)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2851)
    at dao.PessoaDAO.getPessoaPeloCodigo(PessoaDAO.java:83)
    at controller.PessoaController.getPessoaPeloCodigo(PessoaController.java:72)
    at view.VideoPessoa.recuperarPessoas(VideoPessoa.java:461)
    at view.VideoPessoa.btnAlterarActionPerformed(VideoPessoa.java:334)
    at view.VideoPessoa.access$200(VideoPessoa.java:25)
    at view.VideoPessoa$3.actionPerformed(VideoPessoa.java:123)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O diz o seguinte

> java.sql.SQLException: Column 'codigo' not found

No *stack trace* pode-se ver onde esse erro está estourando

> at dao.PessoaDAO.getPessoaPeloCodigo(PessoaDAO.java:83)

Veja essa parte do método `getPessoaPeloCodigo()`

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(SQLPESSOAPELOCODIGO)
...
pessoa.setCodigo(rs.getInt("codigo"));
```

Está sendo passadopara o `PreparedStatement` a *query* contida na constante `SQLPESSOAPELOCODIGO`

Veja a declaração da constante

```
 private final String SQLPESSOAPELOCODIGO = "SELECT nome, endereco, bairro, sexo, 
                                             telefone, celular, CPF, uf, cidade"
        + " FROM pessoa"
        + " WHERE codigo=? ";
```

**Não tem a coluna `codigo` na *query*.**

Esse é o problema.